# How to change the position of a row in UITableView in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, ios7

I used the following tutorial to create a expandable tableview:
[Expandable-Collapsable-TableView](https://github.com/singhson/Expandable-Collapsable-TableView)

My Image:

[image]

I want to reduce the gap between every row from left side. The Distance is too much.
Anyone can help me to position the row.

Comment: hey @vannitec.ch only replace cell.indentationWidth = 10;... check my answer.,,,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
- (UITableViewCell*)createCellWithTitle:(NSString *)title image:(UIImage *)image  indexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath
{
    NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    ExpandableTableViewCell* cell = [self.menuTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        UIView *bgView = [[UIView alloc] init];
        bgView.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];
        cell.selectedBackgroundView = bgView;
        cell.lblTitle.text = title;
        cell.lblTitle.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];

        [cell setIndentationLevel:[[[self.itemsInTable objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"level"] intValue]];

        //**replace your x position**
        cell.indentationWidth = 10;

        float indentPoints = cell.indentationLevel * cell.indentationWidth;

        cell.contentView.frame = CGRectMake(indentPoints,cell.contentView.frame.origin.y,cell.contentView.frame.size.width - indentPoints,cell.contentView.frame.size.height);

        NSDictionary *d1=[self.itemsInTable objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] ;

        if([d1 valueForKey:@"SubItems"])
        {
            cell.btnExpand.alpha = 1.0;
            [cell.btnExpand addTarget:self action:@selector(showSubItems:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        }
        else
        {
            cell.btnExpand.alpha = 0.0;
        }
        return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That's called "indentation".

If you're using a prototype cell in a storyboard/xib, you can directly change its indentation from the cell's Attributes Inspector.

[image]

(You don't have to change the width to 0, if your indentation level is 0).

If not, you can change it programmatically, like:

```
-(void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    cell.indentationLevel = 0;   // No indentation level.
    cell.indentationWidth = 0;   // It's redundant if the level is 0.

}
```

Answer (score 1):

open the `createCellWithTitle` method and change the `cell.indentationWidth` as your self

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
NSString *Title= [[self.itemsInTable objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"Name"];

return [self createCellWithTitle:Title image:[[self.itemsInTable objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"Image name"] indexPath:indexPath];
 } 



- (UITableViewCell*)createCellWithTitle:(NSString *)title image:(UIImage *)image  indexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath
{
    [cell setIndentationLevel:[[[self.itemsInTable objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"level"] intValue]];
    cell.indentationWidth = 40;   //change the width as your self

 }
```

Comment: if u need any help, i help with u

Comment: have a happy day bro,